# Reading email body of email with RMS protection using MAPI

Tags: outlook-addin, mapi

I have a C++ Oulook plugin that reads outgoing emails (during ItemSend event) and analyzes them. When sending an email and adding RMS permission, the PR_BODY_W property of the outgoing email contains (instead of the real body):

```
This message is protected with Microsoft Information Protection. You can 
open it using Microsoft Outlook, which is available for iOS, Android, 
Windows, and Mac OS. Get Outlook for your device here: 
https://aka.ms/protectedmessage.

Microsoft Information Protection allows you to ensure your emails can't be 
copied or forwarded without your permission. Learn more at https://microsoft.com/rms.
```

The real body is retrieved successfully with Outlook Object Model by calling MailItem.Body property.

However, is there a way to read the body using MAPI and not OOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text in PR_BODY really is the real body. However, when Outlook finds an RMS attachment on a message, it substitutes what it finds in that attachment for the real body. The OOM masks this behavior for you. Using MAPI, you'll have to do the decode yourself.

RMS attachments in Outlook/Exchange messages is governed by [[MS-OXORMMS]: Rights-Managed Email Object Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463909(v=exchg.80).aspx). Specifically, you're interested in [Opening a Rights-Managed Email Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200885(v=exchg.80).aspx).

Here's the general outline:

1. Grab [PidNameRightsManagementLicense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee178716(v=exchg.80).aspx) from the message.
2. Locate attachments with a message class of ["rpmsg.message"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157757(v=exchg.80).aspx)
3. Unzip the attachment following [RFC 1950](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt)
4. Continue unpacking data from the attachment following the protocol doc.
5. ...

Knowing that all of this is governed by OXORMMS, we can find the following project on GitHub which might be instructive: https://github.com/damico/test-inflate-rms.

Comment: Nope, not the answer, but nice text looking like an answer. Nothing about the important bit which is decryption of the unzip, with the license and xrml.