Need to add "Confidential/Internal use editable" label while sending an mail from outlook using smtp server in python
I have the below code for sending an email using the SMTP server:
import smtplib
import email.message as EM

try:
    smtp_server = ''
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
    smtp.ehlo()
    from_address = ''
    to_address = ''
    header = EM.Message()
    header["From"] = from_address
    header["To"] = to_address
    header["Subject"] = 'Checking Email Functionality'
    header.add_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
    header.set_payload('checking how email function works')
    res = smtp.sendmail(from_address, to_address.split(','), header.as_string())
    print(res)
    smtp.quit()
    print('Shared successfully')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

Below is the mail that I am receiving with the above code:
Without using Sensitivity in header
If I am using Sensitivity and X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Classification in the header, then I am getting the below kind of mail:
header["Sensitivity"] = "Company-Confidential"
header["X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Classification"] = "Confidential/Internal Use"

Output:
Mail with Sensitivity in header
What I want is as below:
Desired Output Image
What changes are required to achieve this format? Can I do this using SMTP? If not, what is the alternative solution?

RFC 4291 says about the sensitivity header:

Values: Personal, private, and company confidential.

(No hyphen between "company" and "confidential".)
The X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Classification header is a non-standard  extension (indicated by the leading X-). You need to check the Microsoft documentation what values it can take.
It may or may not be possible to set this header directly, or the receiving server may discard or rewrite it. Allowing the client to pass this in is a lot like the evil bit.

RMS messages are encrypted; you can probably recreate them, but that would be a lot of work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51248526/332059.
